# How to show the value of input multi selected Angular ngFor

Tags: angular, select, ngfor

Hi im working in Angular i want to show the value of this in the console

This is my object:

```
tipos = [
    {
      types: 'HEXO',
      descrip: 'Hora extra',
    },
    {
      types: 'HEXN',
      descrip: 'Hora extra Nocturna',
    }]

<select id="opciones" name="opciones">
    <option  disbled>Select</option>
    <option  *ngFor="let tipo of tipos; let i = index;"  value={{tipo['types']}}>{{tipo['descrip']}}</option>
  </select>
```

The {{tipo['descrip']}} is working but the value (value={{tipo['types']} ) throws me an error and i dont know how to iterate to see the value in console. Thanks!

Comment: Use property binding for get value. like this `[value]="tipo['types']"`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you meant?

```
  tipos = [
    {
      types: 'HEXO',
      descrip: 'Hora extra',
    },
    {
      types: 'HEXN',
      descrip: 'Hora extra Nocturna',
    }
  ];

<select id="opciones" name="opciones">
  <option disabled>Select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let tipo of tipos" value="{{tipo.types}}}">{{tipo.descrip}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yeah it was a need! But now i can´t show in the console with 
 let hello = document.getElementById('opciones').value . It throws me an error when i add .value. But its solved what i asked,thank you so much